# move_uploaded_file doesnt work and returns false PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

For 2 days I'm trying to find out why I have the problem.However I couldn't find at all.It doesn't show "DOESNT SHOW ME",It returns else statement.The one prints many infos. Please ignore username,product_id , I'm testing that's why I assume them Thank you for who helps

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
        if($conn)
        {
               $product_id = "39";
               $username = "admin";
               $input = $_POST['comment'];
               $subject = $_POST['subject'];
               $type = $_POST['type'];
               $path = "img/products/";
               $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");
               $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
               $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];

               if(strlen($name))
                    {
                    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
                    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                        {
                        if($size<(1024*1024)) // Image size max 1 MB
                            {
                            $actual_image_name = time()."-".$username."-".$subject.".".$ext;
                            $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                            $upload_like= $path.basename($actual_image_name);

                            $done = move_uploaded_file($tmp,$upload_like);
                            if($done){  
                                    echo "DOESNT SHOW ME :(";

                                    //$insert_image = "UPDATE post SET product_img = '$upload_like' WHERE username='$username' AND id='$product_id";
                                    //$run_image = $conn -> query($insert_image);

                                    $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO post (username,subject,user_post,time_added,type,product_img) VALUES ('$username','$subject','$post', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , '$type','$upload_like')";
                                       $run_sql = $conn -> query($insert_sql);
                                       if($run_sql)
                                       {
                                            echo "DONE";
                                       }
                                       else
                                        {
                                            echo "Something crazy happened.OMG!";
                                        }

                                }
                            else
                                echo "failed". "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
                                echo "Actual Image Name: " .$actual_image_name . "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
                                echo "Path To: ".$path. "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
                                echo "Temp: " .$tmp. "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
                                echo "Last version: ".$upload_like. "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
                                echo "Subject: ".$subject. "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
                                echo "Message: ".$input. "<br>" . PHP_EOL;
                                echo "Type: ".$type. "<br>" . PHP_EOL;


                            }
                        else
                            echo "Image file size max 1 MB";
                        }
                    else
                        echo "Invalid file format..";
                    }
                else
                    echo "Please select image..!";



        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Enable error_reporting() than u can chk the errors

Comment: Also share the info which print, all fine?

Comment: `failed
Actual Image Name: 1476002092-admin-as.jpg
Path To: img/products/
Temp: /tmp/phpVGFCl2
Last version: img/products/1476002092-admin-as.jpg
Subject: as
Message: dasd
Type: 1`

Comment: These are the info, They all correct,  as i wanted . however it doesnt upload

Comment: Chk folder permission or add slash in path $path = "/img/products/";

Comment: i checked already its 0777 which is fine , at least looks fine

Comment: Than try to upload on root $path = ""; path empty. At least u will get an idea what is happening

Comment: Ohh see now !! , it uploaded my files' directory however the file i was trying to upload is on up directory of it . Thank you ! But how can i solve it now? website files in home/.... but im trying to reach img/ they are both under public_html

Comment: Hmm now try to upload in IMG folder first, $path = "/img/" or "img/"

Comment: Try both chk which one working

Comment: Thank you it worked

Comment: Glad to help u.